# Symfony crud generator sql problems

Tags: symfony, generator, crud

I am trying to create simple app using symfony crud generator.

I have these two tables
Airline:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-        mapping"                                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
 <entity name="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Airline" table="airline">
 <id name="id" type="bigint" column="id">
   <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="100" nullable="false"/>
<field name="isActive" type="boolean" column="is_active" nullable="true"/>
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

and destination

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine- mapping.xsd">
 <entity name="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Dest" table="dest">
 <id name="id" type="bigint" column="id">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
  </id>
<field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="100" nullable="false"/>
<field name="isActive" type="boolean" column="is_active" nullable="true"/>
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

the third one is "order"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
 <entity repository-class="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\OrderRepository" name="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Order">
<id name="id" type="bigint" column="id">
  <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
</id>
<field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="255"/>
<field name="airlineId" type="bigint" column="airline_id"/>
<field name="destId" type="bigint" column="dest_id"/>
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

So the two first tables are working properly but the third one gives me an error

```
   An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.name AS name1, t0.airline_id AS         airline_id2, t0.dest_id AS dest_id3, t0.id AS id4 FROM Order t0':

   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order t0' at line 1
```

Everything was generated by symfony so why isnt it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Order** is a reseved word in MySQL , you need to change that name with another one.

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html